# Clarify how to use WITH, AS function in place of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a very basic employees table and trying to filter by those ids that have salaries under a certain level. I know I can use

```
select id, first_name
from employees
where salary < 20000
```

but I was testing out my knowledge of with, as so I used this

```
with black_list as (select id from employees where salary< 20000)

select id, first_name
from employees where salary not in black_list
```

Can someone tell me why this is giving me an error? No matter what I try, the query does not work and I was under the assumption that using WITH, AS could substitute for using a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

`black_list` is just like a table.  It needs to be referenced in a `from` clause:

```
select id, first_name
from employees
where salary not in (select salary from black_list);
```

Of course, this will fail, because `salary` is not a column in `black_list`.  But it is what you are attempting.

I would write what you want using `not exists` rather than `not in`.  That would be:

```
select e.id, e.first_name
from employees e.
where not exists (select 1
                  from black_list bl
                  where bl.id = e.id
                 );
```

Also note the use of table aliases and qualified column names.

Comment: Apologies what if I had  `from employees where id not in black_list` ? How come that also does not work. This time around, my column id is in the black_list temporary table.

Comment: @Rain . . . As the second sentence in the answer states:  you have to reference it in a **from** clause.  Or, to phrase it differently, `not in` can take a list of values or a subquery and `blacklist` is neither of those.